# how can i check if two div touch each other in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a div that runs from left to right.
and a div that goes up and down.
i want to check if they intersect with eachother
(kinda like a jumping from game).
i tried to console.log every point of them (up down left right),
but they just dont meet even if they on the same spot.
i have a code that someone gave me, that if they intersect do something.
the problem is that it says the 'if' is always true.
and if i delete the '!' it doesnt work at all

my code:

```
    $('#startBtn').click(function () {
    moveCars();
})

$('body').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.key == 'ArrowUp') {
        $('#player').css('bottom', '+=140px');
    }

    if ($('#player').css('top') < '0') {
        $('#player').css('bottom', '25px');
    }
});

$('body').keydown(function (e) {

    if ($('#player').css('bottom') <= '20px') {
        if (e.key == 'ArrowDown') {
            $('#player').css('bottom', '20px');
        }
    } else {
        if (e.key == 'ArrowDown') {
            $('#player').css('bottom', '-=140px');
        }
    }
});

function moveCars() {

    $('.carLeft').css('display', 'inline');

    function moveCar() {
        $('.carRight').css('right', '-=2px');

        if ($('.carRight').css('right') <= '0%') {
            $('.carRight').css('right', '105%');
        }
    }

    setInterval(moveCar)

    function moveLeftCars() {
        $('.carLeft').css('left', '-=3px');

        if ($('.carLeft').css('left') <= '0%') {
            $('.carLeft').css('left', '90%');
        }
    }
    setInterval(moveLeftCars)

}


var carsRight = document.querySelector('.carRight');
var carsLeft = document.querySelector('.carLeft');
var player = document.querySelector('#player');

var carRightBound = carsRight.getBoundingClientRect();
var carLeftBound = carsLeft.getBoundingClientRect();
var playerBound = player.getBoundingClientRect();


setInterval(function(carRightBound, playerBound){



    if(!(carRightBound.left > playerBound.right || carRightBound.right < playerBound.left || carRightBound.top > playerBound.bottom || carRightBound.bottom < playerBound.top)) {
        console.log('The divs are intersecting!');
        alert('on here')
    } else {
        console.log('The divs are not intersecting.');
    }

},5000)
```

the setInterval can be deleted.

Comment: You should declare `carRightBound,carLeftBound,playerBound` inside the callback passed to `setInterval`

Comment: Can you post your full code please?

Comment: @obscure i added it to the top

Comment: See if this helps you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection

Comment: @AiltonF.Silva same problem i had. it only enters else now, as if they are not touching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment you're assigning the bounding rectangles of your game objects to the variables carRightBound & playerBound **once** before starting the interval.
That means it's values won't ever get updated anymore. You should update them inside the callback function.

Furthermore the interval of 5000ms is way too long. A lot of stuff can have happenend on screen during 5 seconds. Try reducing it to 50ms for example.

Lastly I'm not too sure about your collision detection anyhow. You aren't paying attention to the size of your objects.

Try this code:

```
setInterval(function() {
  var playerBound = player.getBoundingClientRect();
  var carsRight = document.querySelectorAll('.carRight');
  var carRightBound;

  for (var a = 0; a < carsRight.length; a++) {
    carRightBound = carsRight[a].getBoundingClientRect();
    if (playerBound.x > carRightBound.x - playerBound.width && playerBound.x < carRightBound.x + carRightBound.width && playerBound.y > carRightBound.y - playerBound.height && playerBound.y < carRightBound.y + carRightBound.height) {
      console.log('The divs are intersecting!');
      alert('on here')
    } else {
      console.log('The divs are not intersecting.');
    }
  }
}, 50);
```

Comment: it works but i have two div of carRight. and it only works on one of them.

Comment: Do you mean carsLeft or really another div with the css class .carRight? In the second case you cannot use `document.querySelector('.carRight')` because that will just return the first element matching the class.

Comment: i have two divs with css class ('.carRight'), and another two divs with css class ('.carLeft').

Comment: You need to use `querySelectorAll` instead of `querySelector`. This will return an array of elements you can iterate over using a for-loop. I modified my sample code above.

Comment: obscure God Bless You. i wish you good fortune , success , happines, everything you ever wish for !!

Comment: Hehe, thanks for the kind words Suffering. You're welcome!